# multivariate linear regressions with qualitative independent variable

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm trying to calculate a multivariate linear regressions in which my independent variables are qualitative but Im not sure im doing it right

the code I have so far is

```
model_1.a <- lm(formula = V34 ~ no.work + common.poor.housing + no.degree, data = df)
```

however my variables no.work, common.poor.housing and no.degree where created with the within() function like so:

```
    df <- within(cr.svy, {
  degree <- as.numeric(V6==4)
  no.degree <- as.numeric(V6 == 1| V7 == 2 | V7 == 3)
  work <- as.numeric(V7==1)
  no.work <- as.numeric(V7 == 2)
  common.poor.housing <- as.numeric(V14 == 1 | V14 == 2)
  uncommon.poor.housing <- as.numeric(V14==3 | V14 == 4)
  degree[is.na(V6)] <- NA
  no.degree[is.na(V6)] <- NA
  work[is.na(V7)] <- NA
  no.work[is.na(V7)] <- NA
  common.poor.housing[is.na(V14)] <- NA
  uncommon.poor.housing[is.na(V14)] <- NA
})
```

and are either 1 or 0 and Im not sure if the results are what Im looking for, Im trying to test the relationship between my dependent variables and the no.work, common.poor.housing and the no.degree variable I created

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What makes you think things aren't working?

Comment: the code is working just fine but I'm not sure it is testing the right thing as Im not used to using qualitative variables

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if your data is of class `numeric`, R will treat it as continuous ( quantitative) variable. For variables to be considered categorical (qualitative), they must be of class `factor` which can be easily achieve by taking your variable and applying the function `factor()`. E.g.

```
degree <- factor(degree)
```

This is not necessary, however, if the variable is of class `character` (which in R is very easy to spot, the values will be surronded by quotes). Those variables are automatically converted to `factor` when you call `lm()`.

By looking at your code, your variables are cleary on the first case, `numeric`, since they are created by the function `as.numeric()`.

So, no. Your results are exactly what you want.